# Multithreading- creating new thread for each loop

Tags: java, multithreading

I don't know that much about multi threading but I think that it may be of use to what I am doing. I have something that loops through each graphicNode in my xml file, and creates an object based on the information read. Depending on the object it can take in a query / queries or it will use a stored procedure. The object is then stored in an arrayList. This ends up with my program taking about a minute to start. Is there a way I can create a new thread each time it goes through the loop? Here is my code:

```
            File fXmlFile = f;
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);

            //Normalize the xml file(document)
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

            // All of the nodelists that the XML file uses
            NodeList graphicNodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("graphic");
            NodeList locationNodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("location");
            NodeList gUINodeList  = doc.getElementsByTagName("GUI");
            NodeList storedProcedureNodeList  = doc.getElementsByTagName("storedProcedure");
            NodeList parameterNodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("parameter");
            NodeList dialSpecificNodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("dialSpecific");
            NodeList queriesNodeList=doc.getElementsByTagName("queries");
            NodeList tickerSpecificNodeList=doc.getElementsByTagName("tickerSpecific");
            doc.getElementsByTagName("category");


            // Main loop to get information from each graphical Element.
            for (int temp = 0; temp < graphicNodeList.getLength(); temp++) {
                // Sets the node to the first item in the nodeList
                Node graphicNode = graphicNodeList.item(temp);


                String chartType;

                if (graphicNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                    // Makes an element based off the node.
                    Element eElement = (Element) graphicNode;

                    //Get the Chart type so the system knows what to do with it.
                    chartType= eElement.getAttribute("type");

                    if(chartType.equals("barChartVsTime")){
                        createBarChartVsTime(graphicNode, gUINodeList,locationNodeList, storedProcedureNodeList, parameterNodeList, eElement);
                    }
                    if(chartType.equals("sqlTable")){
                        createSQLTable(graphicNode, gUINodeList, eElement);
                    }
                    if(chartType.equals("dialChart")){
                        createDialChart(graphicNode, gUINodeList, dialSpecificNodeList, eElement);
                    }
                    if(chartType.equals("hourlyDialChart")){
                        createHourlyDialChart(graphicNode, gUINodeList, dialSpecificNodeList, eElement);
                    }
                    if(chartType.equals("colorBlock")){
                        createColorBlock(graphicNode, gUINodeList, eElement);
                    }
                    if(chartType.equals("image")){
                        createImageBlock(graphicNode, gUINodeList, eElement);
                    }
                    if(chartType.equals("threePointAverageChart")){
                        createThreePointAverageChart(graphicNode, gUINodeList,locationNodeList, storedProcedureNodeList, parameterNodeList, eElement);
                    }
                    if(chartType.equals("yieldDialChart")){
                        createYieldDialChart(graphicNode, gUINodeList, locationNodeList, storedProcedureNodeList, dialSpecificNodeList, parameterNodeList, eElement);
                    }

                    if(chartType.equals("ticker")){
                        createTicker(graphicNode, gUINodeList,tickerSpecificNodeList, queriesNodeList, eElement);
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think you'll reap more benefits if you take the time to read the documentation about threads and such, giving it your best shot, making mistakes (that's ok), and, then, if you're still stuck, posting back with what you've tried and what you still need help with.

Comment: Im sure that will help. Does it seem possible at least?

Comment: I'm convinced you will find a solution to your problem.  But first you need to be aware that threads are not a silver bullet solution that you can just throw at any performance problem blindly, just like a hammer is not the right tool for every job.  Based on your question, I really feel that you need to take a step back and learn (through reading and exercises) what threads can and can't do for you, and whether a threaded solution is appropriate for your task at hand.

Comment: In particular, quite often the more threads you throw at a task, the slower it will become overall.

Comment: Threading will improve this. However be warned. You should check basics like number of concurrent threads for an application depends on the number of cores associated with its process. For example:f tasks spend 50 percent of the time being blocked, then the number of threads should be twice the number of available cores.If they spend less time being blocked—that is, they’re computation intensive—then we should have fewer threads but no less than the number of cores.

Answer (score 2):

> I don't know that much about multi threading but I think that it may be of use to what I am doing.
>
> This ends up with my program taking about a minute to start

You're getting ahead of yourself. You should profile your code, first, to see where you're taking the performance hit. Take a look at VisualVM for this. You might have accidentally written an O(n^2) algorithm.

> Depending on the object it can take in a querie(s) or it will use a stored procedure.

I bet it's here. You might be better served by connection pooling or batch requests than immediately diving into threading.

Answer (score 0):

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30945845/variable-callables-with-different-return-types/30984306#30984306) address a similar problem.

So basically you need to create a new `runnable` for each task, Below is an example (Although I have not tested it but will give you an idea):

> Dispatcher.java

```
package com.test.thread;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Dispatcher {

    public void dispatch() throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        ExecutorService cachePool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        for (TaskName taskName : TaskName.values()) {
            cachePool.submit(taskName.worker());
        }
        cachePool.awaitTermination(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        new Dispatcher().dispatch();
    }
}
```

> TaskName.java

```
package com.test.thread;

import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public enum TaskName {
    BarChartVsTime {
        @Override
        public Runnable worker(Document doc) {
            return new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    System.out.println("Thread1");
                    //createBarChartVsTime(graphicNode, gUINodeList,locationNodeList, storedProcedureNodeList, parameterNodeList, eElement);
                }
            };
        }
    },
    SqlTable {
        @Override
        public Runnable worker(Document doc) {
            return new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    System.out.println("Thread2");
                    // createSQLTable(graphicNode, gUINodeList, eElement);
                }
            };
        }
    },
    DialChart {
        @Override
        public Runnable worker(Document doc) {
            return new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    System.out.println("Thread3");
                    // createDialChart(graphicNode, gUINodeList, dialSpecificNodeList, eElement);
                }
            };
        }
    },
    HourlyDialChart {
        @Override
        public Runnable worker(Document doc) {
            return new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    System.out.println("Thread4");
                    // createHourlyDialChart(graphicNode, gUINodeList, dialSpecificNodeList, eElement);
                }
            };
        }
    };
    public abstract Runnable worker(Document doc);

}
```